# How to set the environment variable in supervisord

Tags: docker, supervisord, amazon-kms

I have a supervisord file where like this

```
[program:decrypt]
command=export KEYTOKEN=$(aws kms decrypt --ciphertext-blob fileb://<(echo %(ENV_TOKENENC)s | base64 -d) --output text --query Plaintext --region %(ENV_REGION)s | base64 -d )
```

I am passing the environment ENV_TOKENENC,ENV_REGION to the container and I can echo those variables and confirm that the docker container is getting them, also the command to decrypt kms value also works.But when I put the kms decrypt command in supervised file it throws error saying ('ENV_REGION')&('ENV_CONSULTOKENENC') which cannot be expanded.
Am I putting the right value in supervisord file?

Comment: It's really best to put this kind of logic in a script and execute the script.

Comment: `supervisord` doesn't start a shell implicitly, so you can't use shell expansions, *unless* you run `command=/bin/sh -c 'export ...; ...'` or such. That's harder to maintain and debug than an external script, however, so I rather strongly suggest the latter.

Answer (score 0):

**Setting an environment variable** is easy, if you're setting it to a constant value:

```
[program:decrypt]
command=/usr/bin/env foo=bar baz=qux /path/to/something ...
```

or, with less overhead:

```
environment=foo="bar",baz="qux"
command=/path/to/something ...
```

---

However, *dynamically generating that variable's value* requires a shell:

```
[program:decrypt]
command=/bin/sh -c 'foo=$(generate-bar) /path/to/something'
```

Note that `export` is not actually needed here, as `var=value something` as part of a single command exports `var` having value `value` during the execution of `something`.